# Converting Date format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting a date format like `Mon Apr 22 2013 12:16:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time) form a javascript to my php function.

I want to store that to my database table in "2013-04-22 12:16:00" format.

Can any one help me to convert this date type.

I tried:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$startDate);
```

But it's giving error as

> date() expects parameter 2 to be long string given

Comment: I am using mysql database.And the datatype of that field is   datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$originalDate = "Mon Apr 22 2013 12:16:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" ;
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

(see [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/date) docs on the PHP site).

or use  [DateTime:](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$source = "Mon Apr 22 2013 12:16:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$date = new DateTime($source);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 22 2013 12:16:00
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 22 2013 12:16:00
?>
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/19BX3mQS)

Comment: Sorry it's giving me result "1970-01-01 01:00:00" But I am passing value in $startDate is "Mon Apr 22 2013 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: I show the demo but sorry to say it's not working in my end..Now it's giving error like <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [&lt;a href='datetime.--construct'&gt;datetime.--construct&lt;/a&gt;]: Failed to parse time string (Mon Apr 22 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) at position 41 (S): Double timezone specification'

Comment: Do u trying it in localhost or in the web ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421635/failed-to-parse-time-string-at-position-41-i-double-timezone-specification

Comment: I am trying it in my local host.I am getting the value by post a javascript value.and use that posted value to convert..

Comment: $.post("../PHP/PhpAction.php?f=entryCalendarEvent", { Id: id, StartDate:calEvent.start});  I want to insert this StartDate feild in the database.I echo the post variable and get the above format there.

Comment: @amitghosh - just use string manipulation to remove the `(India Standard Time)` part of the stamp... you've already specified the timezone (`GMT+0530`). Try `$startDate = preg_replace("/\((.*?)\)/", "", $startDate)` and then run the `$date = new DateTime($source); echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 22 2013 12:16:00`

Comment: Hi Ben D you solve my problem.Thanks a lot.Thanks to every one for help me.Now it's working fine.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `strtotime` to convert the timestamp to unix-format so you can use it in the `date()` function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($startDate));
```

You can also try using the (usually included) `DateTime` class. In particular, have a look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It may help you get around ambiguities in the date string (`strtotime()` will sometimes fail or mis-parse a date string). `DateTime::createFromFormat` allows you to specifically designate the format of the date string so there can be no ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry it's giving me result "1970-01-01 01:00:00" But I am passing value in $startDate is "Mon Apr 22 2013 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to save it as Timestamp so,

```
$startDate = strtotime($javascript_value);    
$result =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$startDate);
```

Comment: it's also giving me "1970-01-01 01:00:00" I think all the answer provided so are are the same.. :(