# Failed to parse time string using carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

There error is

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Wed Mar 04 2020 13:56:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)) at position 41 (p): Double timezone specification
```

Where my code is:

```
Carbon::parse($request->birthday)
```

When i'm dumping the value of `$request-> birthday` the value is `Wed Mar 04 2020 13:56:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)`

Comment: change or set `date_timezone `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421635/failed-to-parse-time-string-at-position-41-i-double-timezone-specification   Answer at the bottom. You can use Carbon::createFromFormat.